# Ghostscript - how to write an text to an existing pdf (without pdfmark)

Tags: ghostscript

I want to add some different text on every page on an existing pdf with ghostscript. 
Can someone help me how to do it? Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

There is no simple way to do this with Ghostscript. (The more complex way would be to write a longish PostScript program that would insert/stamp the text on each page. That would certainly be more work than using pdfmarks).

I suggest you consider to use `pdftk`:

```
 pdftk input.pdf stamp text.pdf output new.pdf
```

Comment: more info here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18769314/add-text-on-1st-page-of-a-pdf-file